# Early Abacus program error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I am attempting to create a simple abacus for a beginner's programming course, and have come across an error that I simply can not get my head around. I've hunted around Google but so far no success. The program will compile in Textpad absolutely fine, and at first it will run fine, displaying the grid and being able to understand what column the mouse is in. However, left clicking to run the addCounter method results in a "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException" error. It directs me to line 50 of AbacusPanel.java which is:

```
myAbacus.addCounter(thisCol);
```

I cannot for the life of me work out what I am doing wrong here, so any help would be really appreciated. I hope Pastebin links are okay.

[AbacusPanel.java](http://pastebin.com/9Bc9NViP)

[AbacusModel.java](http://pastebin.com/ye40aRMD)

Comment: You did not post your code for `AbacusFrame`, but the NullPointer is most likely coming from `myAbacus` being null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't assign your `AbacusModel` to the member variable in the constructor. Should be:

```
public AbacusPanel(int nc, int nr)
    {
            numCols = nc;
            numRows = nr;
            addMouseListener(this);
            this.myAbacus = new AbacusModel(numCols,numRows);
    }
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you very much, don't know how I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't run this as I'm at a Unix computer without a JDK, but I would say it looks like the variable **thisCol** is being given a null value.

Try changing getCol to:

```
   int getCol(int x)
   {
           int r = x*numCols/getWidth();
           System.out.println(r); // is this what you expected?
           return r;
   }
```

Also, the addCounter method is returning a boolean but you don't seem to be testing if it's returning true or false.  This may be why you're getting the nullPointer as it's not successfully adding the counter to the abacus.

Comment: I gave that a go but unfortunately I got the same result. I seem to be able to get column and row values, but the problem arises when I attempt to invoke any methods set out in AbacusModel.java. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: So im guessing that the collumn and row values are what you expeced?

Comment: If I delete all references to the addCounter method then yes the column and row values are as expected.